# How to make a group of objects single-user data?

Tags: objects, linked-data

How do I make a group of objects single user-data i.e unlink them? I know that I can do this hand-by-hand, however, there are about 500 objects, and doing them hand by hand would take a lot of time.

Extra notes: Not *all* of them are linked together. What I mean by this is that objects if I select objects A-E, then objects A, B, and E could be linked together, and objects C & D could be linked together. Also, I want to unlink them because I want to apply all of their scales (Ctr+A: Apply Scale).

Thanks.

Answer (score 0):

You can do this by running Make Single User and then select All when prompted.
Note however that this will bu default only make the Object a single user and not the mesh. You will need to use the menu or change the default in the floating Operator Panel to make the mesh to be single user.

[image]

Comment: Thanks, but now my objects, which are active rigid bodies, are falling through other passive rigid bodies. Any help would be appreciated.